# OSGi bundle is installed and in Active state but not registered and hence no output displayed on console

Tags: apache, osgi

I am new to OSGi world.
    I am using Felix 5.0.1 as OSGi container and Apache Aries Blueprint bundle set.
    Maven 3.2.1 , Eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 2 as IDE. windows 7 Pro OS.

```
I have develop two small application using OSGi bundles.
1] Welcome application it has 3 bundles
    i]   welcomeapi bundle
    ii]  welcomeserver bundle
    iii] welcomeclient bundle 
The api bundle is  having interface , server bundle is implementing the interface and exposing the service.
client bundle is referring/consuming the bundle expose by the server bundle.
this application works fine and desire sys outs are getting properly displayed on Felix command prompt

2] Contact application 
 This application also has 3 bundles 
    i] ContactAPI
    ii] ContactDAO
    iii]ContactHellowWorld

In this application I have done some additional things which are as follows.
i] ContactAPI bundle has one interface and one class. (and NOT having any config.xml)
ii]ContactDAO
This bundle has API/methods that  will take Contactid as input argument , connect to database and fetches the required data such as fname, lname etc. 
and provide these contact details to requester(i.e. ContactHelloWorld bundle).  
iii] ContactHellowWorld bundle has API/methods that will provide Contactid as input argument to the methods of ContactDAO and should get the contact object and  print the values on console.
In short the ContactHelloworld bundle invokes ContactDAO projects API/methods 
contactDAO.getContactList();
contactDAO.getContact(101);
All three bundles of Contact application are installed and are in active state but no output
================================================================================

    42|Installed  |    1|ContactAPI (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
       43|Installed  |    1|ContactDAO (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
       44|Installed  |    1|ContactHelloWorld (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
    g! start 42
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_API [42](R 42.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)) -> [org.apache.felix.framework [0](R 0)]
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Starting BlueprintContainer destruction process for bundle Contact_API
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Not a blueprint bundle or destruction of BlueprintContainer already finished for Contact_API.
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Starting BlueprintContainer destruction process for bundle Contact_API
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Not a blueprint bundle or destruction of BlueprintContainer already finished for Contact_API.
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Scanning bundle Contact_API for blueprint application
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - No blueprint application found in bundle Contact_API
    g! [FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG Contact_API - BundleEvent RESOLVED
    [FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG Contact_API - BundleEvent STARTED
    start 43
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_DAO [43](R 43.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.sql) -> [org.apache.felix.framework [0](R 0)]
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_DAO [43](R 43.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.management) -> [org.apache.felix.framework [0](R 0)]
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_DAO [43](R 43.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.dbcp2)(version>=2.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) -> [org.apache.commons.dbcp2 [9](R 9.0)]
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_DAO [43](R 43.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.javapro.gokul.sample.osgi.spring.contact)(version>=0.0.0)(!(version>=1.0.0))) -> [Contact_API [42](R 42.0)]
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_DAO [43](R 43.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.javapro.gokul.sample.osgi.spring.contactapi)(version>=0.0.0)(!(version>=1.0.0))) -> [Contact_API [42](R 42.0
    ]
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_DAO [43](R 43.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)) -> [org.apache.felix.framework [0](R 0)]
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Starting BlueprintContainer destruction process for bundle Contact_DAO
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Not a blueprint bundle or destruction of BlueprintContainer already finished for Contact_DAO.
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Starting BlueprintContainer destruction process for bundle Contact_DAO
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Not a blueprint bundle or destruction of BlueprintContainer already finished for Contact_DAO.
    [FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG Contact_DAO - BundleEvent RESOLVED
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Scanning bundle Contact_DAO for blueprint application
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - No blueprint application found in bundle Contact_DAO
    g! [FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG Contact_DAO - BundleEvent STARTED
    start 44
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_Hello_World [44](R 44.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.javapro.gokul.sample.osgi.spring.contactapi)(version>=0.0.0)(!(version>=1.0.0))) -> [Contact_API [42
    (R 42.0)]
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_Hello_World [44](R 44.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.javapro.gokul.sample.osgi.spring.impl)(version>=0.0.0)(!(version>=1.0.0))) -> [Contact_DAO [43](R 43
    0)]
    DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_Hello_World [44](R 44.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)) -> [org.apache.felix.framework [0](R 0)]
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Starting BlueprintContainer destruction process for bundle Contact_Hello_World
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Not a blueprint bundle or destruction of BlueprintContainer already finished for Contact_Hello_World.
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Starting BlueprintContainer destruction process for bundle Contact_Hello_World
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Not a blueprint bundle or destruction of BlueprintContainer already finished for Contact_Hello_World.
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - Scanning bundle Contact_Hello_World for blueprint application
    [Gogo shell] DEBUG org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender - No blueprint application found in bundle Contact_Hello_World
    g! [FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG Contact_Hello_World - BundleEvent RESOLVED
    [FelixDispatchQueue] DEBUG Contact_Hello_World - BundleEvent STARTED
    ================================================================================
    All three bundles of Contact application are installed and are in active state but no output

       42|Active     |    1|ContactAPI (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
       43|Active     |    1|ContactDAO (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
       44|Active     |    1|ContactHelloWorld (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
    g!

==============================================================================================================================================================================================
```

on the Felix console getting this following log statements (log level is set to 4)
        DEBUG: WIRE: [Contact_DAO [43](R 43.0)] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7)) -> [org.apache.felix.framework [0](R 0)]
        But then Why I am not getting the same issue in the welcome application ?
        Please have a look at the attached code.

## Any Help will be appreciated.

I just notice that Services exposed by Contact Application are not registered 
As compare to Welcome application Not sure.. Why is it so

## As the entire approach is same for both application

```
   41|Active     |    1|spring-osgi-io (1.2.1)
   42|Active     |    1|WelcomeApi (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
   43|Active     |    1|WelcomeServer (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
   44|Active     |    1|WelcomeClient (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
g! inspect cap service 42
WelcomeServer [42] provides:
----------------------------
service [EMPTY]
g! inspect cap service 43
Welcome_Server [43] provides:
-----------------------------
service; com.javapro.gokul.apache.aries.blueprint.welcomeapi.WelcomeService with properties:
   osgi.service.blueprint.compname = welcomeservice
   service.bundleid = 43
   service.id = 37
   service.scope = bundle
   Used by:
      Welcome_Client [44]
service; org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer with properties:
   osgi.blueprint.container.symbolicname = Welcome_Server
   osgi.blueprint.container.version = 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
   service.bundleid = 43
   service.id = 38
   service.scope = singleton
g! inspect cap service 44
Welcome_Client [44] provides:
-----------------------------
service; org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer with properties:
   osgi.blueprint.container.symbolicname = Welcome_Client
   osgi.blueprint.container.version = 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
   service.bundleid = 44
   service.id = 39
   service.scope = singleton
g!
======================================================================================================================================================
Above Services for Welcome application are registered propely 
======================================================================================================================================================
Below Services for Contact application are NOT registered propely 
======================================================================================================================================================
   42|Active     |    1|WelcomeApi (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
   43|Active     |    1|WelcomeServer (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
   44|Active     |    1|WelcomeClient (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
   45|Active     |    1|ContactAPI (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
   46|Active     |    1|ContactDAO (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
   47|Active     |    1|ContactHelloWorld (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
g! inspect cap service 45
Contact_API [45] provides:
--------------------------
service [EMPTY]
g! inspect cap service 46
Contact_DAO [46] provides:
--------------------------
service [EMPTY]
g! inspect cap service 47
Contact_Hello_World [47] provides:
----------------------------------
service [EMPTY]
g!
```